# OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I have got such error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Using XAMPP and work with codeigniter. May anyone knows what is the problem? thanks in advance

This is the code I run

```
$url = "graph.facebook.com/".$user_profile['id']."/…;; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$fp = fopen("images/results/img".$user_profile['id'].".jpg","wb"); 
if (!$fp) 
    exit; 

fwrite($fp, $data); 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Its basically saying the servers certificate is not valid. Is this your server, or a remote server?

Comment: this is my local server. XAMPP

Comment: But the server you are trying to access with `file_get_conntents` is that yours?

Comment: No, I am trying to get url of facebook user profile picture

Comment: Maybe a little code would help us to help you

Comment: which code? or may be there are settings in XAMPP so i need to change? thanks

Comment: SHow the code that generated this error

Comment: $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_profile['id']."/picture?width=167&height=167";
            $data = file_get_contents($url);
            $fp = fopen("images/results/img".$user_profile['id'].".jpg","wb");
            if (!$fp) exit;
            fwrite($fp, $data);
            fclose($fp);

Comment: ___In the question next time___ I did it for you this time

Comment: ok thanks a lot:) So, is the problem in the coding or i will need to fix some settings?

Comment: I assume you have logged in?

Comment: i work with codeigniter, and i see this message when i load the php file in view

Comment: I mean logged into graph?

Comment: u mean app, yes i did